# Passing arguments to C++ programme for debugging in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmdline-args

I want to debug a C++ project in VSCode (on a Mac, using either GDB or LLDB). The program itself takes command line arguments like

```
./prog -input cf file_x.txt
```

This works fine when starting a debugging session in GDB on the command line.

In VSCode, I tried to adapt `launch.json` to read like this (only relevant lines shown):

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/prog",
            "args": [
              "-input cf",
               "path_to/file_x.txt"
            ]
```

With this, I get `@"Unknown option: \"-input cf\"\r\n"` in the output and the process is not debugged; alternatively, I tried only one argument like so:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/prog",
            "args": [
              "-input cf path_to/file_x.txt"
            ]
```

resulting in the same message. Have I missed something important?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try it like this

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/prog",
            "args": [
              "-input",
              "cf",
              "path_to/file_x.txt"
            ]
```

Comment: I know this is old but this page will be updated with changes. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_args

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, I just do :

```
 "args": [
    "your_arg1",
    "your_arg2"
 ]
```

(in launch.json of course)

Comment: This is already said in the accepted answer, please avoid duplicating information

Comment: I was looking up how to this exact thing and found this page. The answer adds "-input". This is not needed in 2022, hence my answer.

Comment: if that is the case, then you should've commented on the original answer instead